# Bond active backup Linux

Tags: linux-networking, bonding

i am trying to set up a bond on my 4.4 proxmox server.

i chose active-backup because the bond will be linked to a linux bridge which will not use Spanningtree Protocol.

the bond(bond1) will have 2 slaves : Bond0 which is an LACP of 3 links(eth0,eth1,eth2) to 1 switch and eth3 to an other switch.

My problem is that when i unplug Bond0 (primary interface of Bond1)
i unplug all the cables from (eth0 eth1 eth2)

Bond1 keep bond0 as active link and as effect: the server is unreachable from the local network.

i think this is because Bond0 remain UP even when its 3 slaves are down.

because When i do ifconfig bond0 down.

Bond1 use the other link (eth3) for connection. and the server is back on the local network.

that's the way it is supposed to work.

So i tried multiple parameters in bond0, to force it to have a DOWN state when eth0 eth1 and eth2 are DOWN.

I couldn't find out.

i even used the post-down,post-up,.... parameters on eth0 eth1 and eth2 in /etc/network/interface, to trigger a script that do ifdown bond0 when these ports are DOWN and ifup bond0 when one of them is back working.

But this isn't working, i tried unplugging bond0. bond1 still use bond0 as active link. The script isn't running.

At this point i wanted to pull out my hair....

The script is not triggered because. they are executed only when i do ifdown eth0 ifdown eth1 or ifdown eth2...

(post-down,post-up): now i know that these parameters shot a command only when we run ifdown or ifup, but not when we unplug the plug. (seriousely what's the point of this fonctionality).

i want to execute an action when an interface is down and it don't work when i unplug the ethernet cable.....

that's not what i want at all.

i restarted between changes.

i'm kind of desperate right now, i spent 9 hours on this.

so i am asking you your help.

i found a debian package "ifplugd" which will do actions when interfaces are unplugged. I will try it tomorow

I don't really know what's the best practice here.

I am listening of any advices.
Thank you.

update

Here is /etc/network/interface:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
        post-down do_i_bring_bond0_down.sh
        post-up do_i_bring_bond0_up.sh

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
        post-down do_i_bring_bond0_down.sh
        post-up do_i_bring_bond0_up.sh

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet manual
        post-down do_i_bring_bond0_down.sh
        post-up do_i_bring_bond0_up.sh

iface eth3 inet manual


auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
        slaves eth0 eth1 eth2
        bond_miimon 100
        bond_mode 802.3ad
        bond_xmit_hash_policy layer3+4
        bond_min_links 1

auto bond1
iface bond1 inet manual
        slaves bond0 eth3
        bond_miimon 100
        bond_mode active-backup
        bond_primary bond0
        bond_updelay 100
        bond_downdelay 100

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  10.4.2.4
        netmask  255.255.255.192
        gateway  10.4.2.1
        bridge_ports bond1.20
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        bridge_ports bond1
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_vlan_aware yes
```

/proc/net/bonding/bond1

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: bond0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: bond0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 100
Down Delay (ms): 100

Slave Interface: bond0
MII Status: up
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: c8:1f:66:c2:dc:3b
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth3
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 00:15:17:3a:a9:bf
Slave queue ID: 0
```

/proc/net/bonding/bond0

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: IEEE 802.3ad Dynamic link aggregation
Transmit Hash Policy: layer3+4 (1)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

802.3ad info
LACP rate: slow
Min links: 0
Aggregator selection policy (ad_select): stable
System priority: 65535
System MAC address: c8:1f:66:c2:dc:3b
Active Aggregator Info:
        Aggregator ID: 2
        Number of ports: 3
        Actor Key: 9
        Partner Key: 67
        Partner Mac Address: 80:2a:a8:df:42:b1

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: c8:1f:66:c2:dc:3b
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 2
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 1
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: c8:1f:66:c2:dc:3b
    port key: 0
    port priority: 255
    port number: 1
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 32768
    system mac address: 80:2a:a8:df:42:b1
    oper key: 67
    port priority: 128
    port number: 8
    port state: 61

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: c8:1f:66:c2:dc:3c
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 2
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: c8:1f:66:c2:dc:3b
    port key: 0
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 32768
    system mac address: 80:2a:a8:df:42:b1
    oper key: 67
    port priority: 128
    port number: 7
    port state: 61

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: 00:15:17:3a:a9:be
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 2
Actor Churn State: none
Partner Churn State: none
Actor Churned Count: 1
Partner Churned Count: 1
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 65535
    system mac address: c8:1f:66:c2:dc:3b
    port key: 0
    port priority: 255
    port number: 3
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 32768
    system mac address: 80:2a:a8:df:42:b1
    oper key: 67
    port priority: 128
    port number: 9
    port state: 61
```

Comment: Please post your exact bonding configuration and the contents of "/proc/net/bonding/bond*" when unplugging the cables.

Comment: i have updated my post.

Comment: i have updated my post. You can notify that bond0 remain UP even when his slaves are down. and bond1 is keepink bond0 as active slave, Thank you

Comment: the scripts that i am using on eth0 eth1 and eth2 do nothing when i unplug.

Comment: when they are not there, results are the same.

Comment: where you create bond1.20 ? because I think, you used but you never defined that interface.

Comment: @c4f4t0r these line just say that all frames who go thought the vmbr0 bridge and want to go out by bond1 will be untagged with vlan20.

Comment: you have to define eth0 and then you can use virtuals interfaces eth0.10 , eth0.15 , etc ... not sure that's the complete truth, check documentation. but i don't think this is the source of my problems here, thank you

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Link_Aggregation_.28LACP.29_with_VLANs

Comment: @c4f4t0r that's an other way to do it i guess, i already tested that configuration my physical switch see frames that come from the vmbr0 are vlan20 untagged, i tested communications between vlans with multiple machines. and i could not reach the server with other vlans. even with the same IP range. But i can reach the server with a machine which in vlan20 untagged or with my intervlan routing enabled on my router.

Comment: And the server is plugged to my switch ports (lacp) which are tagged with multiple vlans. Not untagged VLAN20, i think that i can be sure that the frames are untagged vlan 20 when they go from the server (vmbr0) to my network.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bond bonds, this configuration is wrong.

See my other answer for a way to achieve "failover between bonds" solely with LACP, which is the correct configuration: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82569/bonds-vs-aggregators/172232#172232

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems to be this: "Min links: 0". From the [bonding documentation for the min_links parameter](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt)

> min_links
>
> This allows setting the minimum number of member ports that must be up
>   (link-up state) before marking the bond device as up (carrier on)
>
> The default value is 0. This will cause carrier to be asserted (for
>     802.3ad mode) whenever there is an active aggregator, regardless of the number of available links in that aggregator.

However, this part is somewhat confusing:

> Note that, because an aggregator cannot be active without at least one
>   available link, setting this option to 0 or to 1 has the exact same
>   effect.

In your bond0 example all three eth interfaces have MII status (link-state) of down but the aggragator they are in (2) is active which seems to contradict the documentation. Let's look at the source.

The code for bond_3ad_set_carrier() calls __agg_active_ports() which simply checks the value of the "is_enabled" flag of each dev and has seemingly nothing to do with link status.

[This patch](https://github.com/opennetworklinux/linux/blob/master/3.2.65-1%2Bdeb7u2/patches/network-bonding-fix-min-links.patch) seems to indicate that this is the case:

> For now, the patch uses number of active slaves to compare against
>   min_links to know when to on/off bond carrier.  Suggested setting of
>   min_links is 1, rather than the default of zero.  Using min_links=1
>   says that atleast 1 slave must be active within bond for bond to be
>   carrier on.

From what I can tell the patch hasn't been integrated into mainline or maybe it has in a modified form I could not discern.

Try setting min_links to 1 or 2 and see what happens. If that doesn't work you could switch from miimon to arp monitoring (setting arp_interval apr_ip_target, etc.)

P.S. If you end up using LACP I'd change lacp_rate from the default (slow LACPDUs every 30 seconds - i.e. time to detect failure is 30 seconds) to fast or 1 (Request partner to transmit LACPDUs every 1 second).

Edit: Looking into the code more has made me question my answer. The bond_3ad_handle_link_change() function should disable a dev when the link status changes. Maybe you didn't wait 30+ seconds for the LACP state machine to work? I'll leave the answer nontheless because I spent so much time on it. :)